# Mac command line: zsh: command not found: mvn

Tags: macos, zsh

I installed maven in `/Users/chenmin/software/apache-maven-3.6.3`, and when I type `cat ~/.bash_profile`, it returns:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/chenmin/software/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/support-files
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/chenmin/software/apache-tomcat-8.5.58/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/chenmin/software/apache-tomcat-8.5.58/logs
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/chenmin/software/redis/6.0.9/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/chenmin/software/rabbitmq
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
```

and `/Users/chenmin/software/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin` is also included in the variable `$PATH`. However, everytime I open a new command window and type a `mvn` command (e.g. `mvn clean install`), it suggests `zsh: command not found: mvn`, and when I type `source ~/.bash_profile`, the command could be executed correctly, even though I had not modify the file `~/.bash_profile`, can anyone answer why?

Comment: @MinChen : If you want to see your PATH, it is pointless to `cat` any file. I would simply do a `echo $PATH` or `echo $path[*]`. Finally, I don't understand why you are tagging your post with `zsh`, but fiddle around with a bash startup file. Please make up your mind whether we are talking bash or zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using zsh now, you may have to use `~/.zshrc` rather than the `~/.bash_profile`.